# Programmers.SE twitter account?

Tags: support, status-completed, twitter

I noticed that there's a twitter account for most SE websites, but not programmers

Any idea why's that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there is: [@StackProgrammer](http://twitter.com/StackProgrammer).